# Extensions of the $p$-adic valuation to $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I'm trying to find all the possible non-archimedean places (absolute value equivalence classes) on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. I know that every valid absolute value on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ must also be a valid absolute value on $\mathbb{Q}$, and I know that the every non-archimedean absolute value on $\mathbb{Q}$ is equivalent to the $p$-adic absolute value for some prime $p$, so I figured the best way to start would be trying to extend the $p$-adic absolute value to $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

I know every place on a field is equivalent to a choice of a valuation ring, and the most natural extension of the $p$-adic valuation ring I thought of was the integral closure of $\mathbb{Q}\cap\mathbb{Z_p}$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. ($\mathbb{Q}\cap\mathbb{Z_p}$ is the set of rational $p$-adic integers for some prime $p$, or the rational numbers whose denominator is not divisible by $p$ in lowest form)

My questions:

1. Is this a valid valuation ring? I have absolutely no idea how to go about proving whether this satisfies the definition. All I can think to do is try to find a counterexample, and I haven't found one. For every element of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$  that isn't in the integral closure of $\mathbb{Q}\cap\mathbb{Z_p}$ that I checked, the inverse *is* in the integral closure of $\mathbb{Q}\cap\mathbb{Z_p}$.
2. If it is a valid valuation ring, does it correspond to a real absolute value? I've read somewhere that some equivalent conditions for valuation ring corresponding to a real absolute value are: it has Krull dimension 1, it is a maximal proper subring of its field of fractions, and it is completely integrally closed (Note: I haven't seen a proof for any of these conditions). Again, I have no idea where to begin in proving this.
3. If the above are true, how do you actually define the valuation based on the choice of valuation ring? For some cases, like for a complex root of a rational number, it's easy:  The absolute value of the $n$th root is the $n$th root of the absolute value. But in the general case (i.e the root of a general polynomial with rational coefficients, or some expression with radicals) I don't know how you would go about this. Ideally for rational numbers the absolute value should correspond to the standard $p$-adic absolute value ($|x|_p=p^{-v_p(x)}$)
4. Are all the non-archimedean places on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ of this form?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not think in terms of primes? Extensions of the $p$-adic absolute value correspond to prime ideals of $\overline{\mathbb Z}$ above $p$.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but I don't think the ring you've constructed will be a valuation ring. Specifically, I don't see how it would enable you to choose a specific prime above $p$. I think the construction would fail if you used it to construct the extensions of the $p$-adic valuation to a finite extension in which $p$ splits completely. If it fails for finite extensions, it fails for infinite ones too.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I don't fully understand your logic. I'm self taught, and I'm learning from the internet instead of any comprehensive book, so I probably don't know all the relevant theorems. Do you have any (not paywalled) literature you could recommend so I could understand better?

Comment: Also, what is $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$? Is it the ring of all algebraic integers? I've never seen $\mathbb{Z}$ with the bar before.

Comment: Getting late here so I cannot think straight. But the kind of problems Mathmo123 may also have in mind may be the following. In $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ we have two primes over $5$, as $5=(2+i)(2-i)$. Hence there are two distinct valuation rings of $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ that both intersect $\Bbb{Q}$ at $\Bbb{Q}\cap\Bbb{Z}_5$. Anything integral over $\Bbb{Q}\cap\Bbb{Z}_5$ is thus in the intersection of those two valuations rings. That leaves elements like $(2+i)/(2-i)=(3+4i)/5$ and $(2-i)/(2+i)=(3-4i)/5$ neither of which is integral over $\Bbb{Q}\cap\Bbb{Z}_5$ even though they are reciprocals.

Comment: And when you go to higher degree extensions instead of the simple $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ you would expect it to get worse, no?

Comment: Agreeing with Mathmo123 and Jyrki (nice concrete example). By the way, a standard way to write $\mathbb Q \cap \mathbb Z_p$ is $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$, the localisation of $\mathbb Z$ at $(p)$.

Comment: Is this of interest to you? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5718/what-is-the-relationship-between-non-archimedean-places-of-infinite-extensions-o

Comment: Possibly I should have spelled out that the reciprocal numbers I gave are **both** zeros of
$$x^2-\frac65\,x+1.$$
This might make it clear that neither of them is integral over $\Bbb{Q}\cap\Bbb{Z}_5$. Hopefully it also serves to point out the error in the thought process that lead to think that the said integral closure would be a valuations ring.

Comment: OK, I understand. Thanks