# Primes vs valuations of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I know valuations on $\mathbb{Q}$ extend to valuations on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ (though I don't know the details of this, any reference would be appreciated). On the other hand I assume the ring of integers in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$, contains non-zero prime ideals. Do these two sets coincide? That is, do all (non-archimedean) valuations on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ come from a prime ideal of $\mathcal{ O}_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$ and vice versa?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5718/what-is-the-relationship-between-non-archimedean-places-of-infinite-extensions-o

Comment: Oh great thanks!